# Lazy Loading Not Compiling Angular2 Webpack

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I am trying to make my components to lazily load on clicking the Url but i am getting a error on Compile Time and not able to get what it is please help .

i am using webpack for bundling this app.

My AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {
  NgModule,
  ApplicationRef
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  RouterModule,
  PreloadAllModules
} from '@angular/router';
import {CountDown} from "../../node_modules/angular2-simple-countdown/countdown";

/*
 * Platform and Environment providers/directives/pipes
 */
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CompetitionComponent } from './competition/competition.component';
import { CompetitionService } from './shared/competition.service';

import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { TeamComponent } from "./team/team.component";
import { TeamResolve } from "./team/team.resolve";
import { TableModule } from './table/table.module';


@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,CompetitionComponent,TeamComponent,CountDown
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    routing,
    TableModule
  ],
  providers:[CompetitionService,TeamResolve]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

My App Routing File

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CompetitionComponent } from './competition/competition.component';
import { TeamComponent } from "./team/team.component";
import { TeamResolve } from "./team/team.resolve";


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component:  CompetitionComponent},
  { path: 'table', loadChildren:'app/table/table.module#TableModule'},
  { path: 'team', component: TeamComponent,resolve: {team: TeamResolve}  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

My Table Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TableComponent } from './table.component';
import { KeysPipe } from "../shared/keys.pipe";
import { TableResolve } from "./table.resolve";
import { tableRouting } from "./table.routing";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    TableComponent,KeysPipe
  ],
  imports:[CommonModule,tableRouting],
  providers:[TableResolve]
})

export class TableModule{

}
```

My Table Routing

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TableComponent } from './table.component';
import { TableResolve } from "./table.resolve";


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TableComponent,resolve: {table: TableResolve} }
    ];

export const tableRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

StackTrace on Browser console

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ng-router-loader - Invalid code generator "async-import"
    at Loader.replaceSource (D:\Angular2\Football\node_modules\src\Loader.ts:104:29)
    at Loader.replace (D:\Angular2\Football\node_modules\src\Loader.ts:66:22)
    at Object.loader (D:\Angular2\Football\node_modules\index.ts:1
```

Comment: Can you provide plunker working example?

Comment: Sorry mate like plunker is disabled in my corp network

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some thought. I think the problem in ng-router-loader could be related to versions/breaking changes. What I suggest to do is to try to vary package versions in package.json for all angular modules. E.g. v 2.4.0 or v2.3.1. It could be a bug.

Based on your current code, nothing can be said about the problem. Nothing except error message looks wrong.

PS: You are not using angular-cli, what starter kit or project are you using for you angular app? Did you configure webpack yourself?

Comment: no i am using angular 2 starter pack from git 
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: got it to work , changed to the latest version of the Starter pack , thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear error:

> ng-router-loader - Invalid code generator "async-import"

You did not include your webpack config, but in it, where the TS loader configuration is, you need to set the code generator for ng-router-loader.

You set to async-import which is only supported in the latest version of ng-router-loader, so either update it or set to async-require

this is how the loaders should be set for TS files:

```
        {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
          options: {
            pretty: !isProd,
            prod: isProd
          }
        },
        { // MAKE SURE TO CHAIN VANILLA JS CODE, I.E. TS COMPILATION OUTPUT.
          loader: 'ng-router-loader',
          options: {
            loader: 'async-import',
            genDir: 'compiled',
            aot: AOT
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          options: {
            configFileName: 'tsconfig.webpack.json'
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
        }
      ],
      exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    },
```